# Who know Module similar my image?

Tags: joomla, module

Who know module joomla 3.x similar my attach image.for free?

[image]

### Heading

Answer (score 0):

everything and always for free...

Checkout GAVICK.com News Show Module
otherwise YOOTHEME Widgetkit could also be a good solution but costs some money...

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 3 free extensions that can be useful to your needs:

- [RokSprocket](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/news-display/articles-display/roksprocket)
- [BT Content Slider](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/news-display/articles-display/bt-content-slider)
- [News Show Pro GK5](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/news-display/articles-display/news-show-pro-gk5)

Regards.